# Django syncdb not respecting collation and encoding

Tags: mysql, django

I'm setting up a project that'll be available in 16 languages so I'm trying to setup the database for unicode characters using the following init command;

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': DATABASE_NAME,
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',

        'STORAGE_ENGINE': 'INNODB',
        'CONN_MAX_AGE': 100,
        'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': True,

        'OPTIONS': {
            'init_command': 'SET storage_engine=INNODB,character_set_connection=utf8,collation_connection=utf8_unicode_ci',
        },
    }
}
```

When I check the tables created from `python manage.py syncdb` they're set to latin1. Is what I've got correct? Or am I making a mistake using the `init_command` for collation & encoding?

Comment: ALTER SCHEMA `DATABASE_NAME`  DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ;

Comment: @madzohan Can't django do this for me though? I don't want to deploy to a server, then have to go on and run this just to get things setup.

Comment: your default `character_set_server` is latin1, try add `set global character_set_server=utf8; set session character_set_server=utf8;`  to `init_command`

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure if it might be the server defaults that weren't allowing django to use those settings.