# How to prevent multiple login in Django

Tags: django, session

I'm writing a User system that cannot login at the same time.
If the account in login state in somewhere, and someone login the same account in other position. The latter one will be logged in. And the previous will be logged out.
I'm using a model with oneToOneField associated to the User model, And save session ids of this user. 
The code is like below.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .myModels import JSONField

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, models.CASCADE)
    sessionids = JSONField(null=True)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
```

The JSONField is a field that using textField to store JSON string.
When a user login, I go to get all session ids of this user and delete all the session ids. Then I add current session id to the Profile. By doing this, I can logout in the previous position. the code is like below.

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return HttpResponse("the user session is authenticated.")

        username = request.POST.get('username', '')
        password = request.POST.get('password', '')

        user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        if user is not None and user.is_active:
            auth.login(request, user)

            #remove cur user all sessions
            sessionidsToDelete = request.user.profile.sessionids
            if sessionidsToDelete != None:
                sessions = Session.objects.filter(session_key__in=sessionidsToDelete)
                for session in sessions:
                    session.delete()

            #add cur user sessions
            sessionidsToStore = user.profile.sessionids
            print("sessionidsToStore = ")
            print(sessionidsToStore)
            print("sessionidsToDelete = ")
            print(sessionidsToDelete)

            if sessionidsToStore== None:
                sessionidsToStore = []
            else:
                sessionidsToStore = list(set(sessionidsToStore) - set(sessionidsToDelete))
            print("sessionidsToStore = ")
            print(sessionidsToStore)
            sessionidsToStore.append(request.session.session_key)
            user.profile.sessionids = json.dumps(sessionidsToStore)
            user.profile.save()

            rotate_token(request)
            return HttpResponse("login sucessful")
        elif user.is_active == False:
            userNotActivedHttpresponse = HttpResponse()
            userNotActivedHttpresponse.status_code = 605
            userNotActivedHttpresponse.reason_phrase = "This user not active"
            return userNotActivedHttpresponse
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Please Input the correct username and password")
    else:
        return HttpResponseBadRequest("Please use POST to login")
```

But I think something will happen. When there two people want to login the same account at the same time. 
For example, there are two people know the same account.
They login at the same time. It may be happen that B append B's session id to Profile after A remove all other session ids. In this situation, A and B will still in login state, and won't be logout. How could I prevent this problem?

Comment: Typically such race conditions are not possible, since views run in transactions. But regardless, this is not ideal modelling. You probably better use a login hook for this, that checks if the user is already logged in, and then remove that session.

Comment: Oh! I forgot Django supply login hook. Thanks.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: But I found that the views run in transactions only if add transaction.atomic decorator in [Document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/transactions/)

Comment: well the document states "*A common way to handle transactions on the web is to wrap each request in a transaction. **Set `ATOMIC_REQUESTS` to `True`** in the configuration of each database for which you want to enable this behavior.*" https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/transactions/#tying-transactions-to-http-requests I think somehow I'm quite used to this setting :S, most (if not all) `settings.py` I've seen have this feature.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: Ok, I know how to do now. Thank you!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think you make things very complicated, by storing data in `UserProfile`s, etc. and then have signals, you introduce a lot of levels, and at each level, things can go wrong.

We basically need two things here: a table that maps `User`s to their corresponding settings. We can implement this with a `UserSession` model:

```
# models.py

from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session

class UserSession(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    session = models.OneToOneField(Session, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

So the `UserSession` object makes a link between `User` and `Session`s. Now we can implement a *login hook*: a signal that is triggered in case a user logs in. In that case we perform two things:

1. we delete all `Session`s (and corresponding `UserSession`s) of the `User` that are active; and
2. we create a new `Session` and corresponding `UserSession` that we can remove later. Like:

```
from django.contrib.auth import user_logged_in
from django.dispatch.dispatcher import receiver

@receiver(user_logged_in)
def remove_other_sessions(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
    # remove other sessions
    Session.objects.filter(usersession__user=user).delete()
    
    # save current session
    request.session.save()

    # create a link from the user to the current session (for later removal)
    UserSession.objects.get_or_create(
        user=user,
        session_id=request.session.session_key
    )
```

**Update**: I wrapped this into a [small reusable app <sup>[GitHub]</sup>](https://github.com/hapytex/django-single-session) that can be installed through pip.

Comment: I have tried that using one to one field to associate to the session and a foreign key to the user. But after I migrate, I got an error `django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1005, "Can't create table 'django_database.#sql-ab2_75f6d' (errno: 150)")`

Comment: Does, by any change the collation of your database is set differently than the collection of the primary key of a session?

Comment: No, it's the default session. 
The session table is django_session. And there are three fields : "session_key", "session_data", "expire_data".

Comment: @fnsne: yes, but that does not matter. The point is that a database attaches collation to it. And unfortunately sometimes that collation is different from the database one, and then foreign keys fail to get created. That is one of the reasons why using non-integer primary keys is usually a bad idea :(.

Comment: @fnsne: see for example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26655888/django-syncdb-not-respecting-collation-and-encoding

Comment: Oh! I had changed the charset to utf8mb4. Maybe that is where the error happened.

Comment: @fnsne: well a problem with text is that it is not straightforward to specify when two text fields are the same. A result is that these are typically not well suited for foreign keys.

Comment: Sadly i got: Session matching query does not exist.

Comment: @Venom: then it looks like the middleware did not create a session object when you logged in, which seems to suggest something is broken with that part.

Comment: My mistake was that i had the wrong settings configured at settings.py Make sure you have "SESSION_ENGINE = "django.contrib.sessions.backends.db"
SESSION_CACHE_ALIAS = "default"

Comment: Is there any possibility this is working with: django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache at settings.py would be awesome to stor all the session data at redis

Comment: Just out of curiosity. If session object for current user is deleted, won't get_or_create always create, since deleting session will automatically delete usersession y models.CASCADE?

Comment: Django 3.2: Instead of `request.session.save()` (which doesn't work), I had to use `request.session.save(True)` .. but found it better to just use: `request.session.cycle_key()`.

Comment: Why call save() on session, when inside the signal we know user is already logged in?

Answer (score -2):

Since you want the user to have only one session at a time, you can call logout before you call login

```
...
if user is not None and user.is_active:
    auth.logout(request)
    auth.login(request, user)
```

Logout documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.logout

Comment: This logs out the user associated with that request object and thus that session id. It doesn't iterate over all sessions associated with the user. However, it's the best approach that doesn't rely on Session being of the Database backend, but you'd have to implement `user_logged_out` signal and do the iteration over existing sessions yourself.

Comment: @Melvyn In a new application this approach should always have single session for a user. In an application that is already deployed, you will have to run a one time code to iterate and remove multiple session. Why user_logged_out signal is required?

Comment: This will not logout the user on other sessions, only the session with the `request`. This thus means that if the user is using another browser (on the same or different device), it will use another session, and the user will *not* logout the user on the other sessions. Using the `user_logged_in` signal is not required: you can logout the other sessions by overriding the view, but `auth.logout` will *not* logout the user in the other sessions. This is not even possible since at that point in time `request.user` is an `AnonymousUser`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I will check it and update.