# Django revoke session key if logged in from another device/browser

Tags: django, session, middleware

i want to revoke the old session as soon as the user logs-in from another device but if i use session flush here i get logged out from all browsers. has smb a solution for this:

middleware.py

```
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session
# Session model stores the session data
from .models import LoggedInUser


class OneSessionPerUserMiddleware:
    # Called only once when the web server starts
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            session_key = request.session.session_key
            try:
                logged_in_user = request.user.logged_in_user
                stored_session_key = logged_in_user.session_key
                if stored_session_key != session_key:
                    Session.objects.filter(session_key=stored_session_key).delete()
                logged_in_user.session_key = session_key
                logged_in_user.save()
            except LoggedInUser.DoesNotExist:
                LoggedInUser.objects.create(user=request.user, session_key=session_key)
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response
```

Comment: Related: I constructed such utility ~1 year ago, although I do not know if this fully is what you want. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50834410/67579

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem thanks for your quick answere, that seems ideed smart. does everything happen at models.py?
Im asking because i subclassed a lot from django contrib auth. thanks again!