# How to prevent multiple user login in django(note: When first user is login , prevent second user to login )

Tags: python, django, session, middleware

I am developing an Django application using django auth module and would like to prevent multiple login using the same user name and password.

It should prevent multiple logins on different machines using the same user name and password. When the second user tries to login in same account, the second shouldn't get access unless the first logout .

Comment: Hope it will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50833980/how-to-prevent-multiple-login-in-django

Comment: @Eyal.D I want the second one not to get the access until the first is logeed out

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can do something like this(based on this [**`answer`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50834410/2696165)):

First, have a model to have connection between session and user:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session

class UserSession(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    session = models.OneToOneField(Session, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Then create your custom authenticate method(create [**`custom backend`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend)):

```
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend

class MyBackend(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
         if Session.objects.filter(usersession__user__username=username).exists():
             return None
         else:
             user = super().authenticate(request, username=username, password=password, **kwargs)
             if user:
                  request.session.save()
                  UserSession.objects.get_or_create(
                       user=user,
                       session=Session.objects.get(pk=request.session.session_key)
                  )
             return user
```

Then use this backend in `settings.py`:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ['path.to.MyBackend']
```

Comment: I got an error on session=Session.objects.get(pk=request.session.session_key) what might be the problem

Comment: I tried it and I got error like Query for this session doesn't exist. I have get_or_create if it session doesn't exist Why do I still get that error

Comment: did you ran `request.session.save()`?