# Django preventing multiple user logins

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I wanted to limit users to one login per account.  I read numerous posts, and I've been following this post in particular:  [How to prevent multiple login in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50833980/how-to-prevent-multiple-login-in-django).

In myapp/models.py, I have this:

```
    from django.conf import settings
    from django.db import models
    from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session
...
    class UserSession(models.Model):
        user_acc = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        session_manager = models.OneToOneField(Session, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

In myaurth/views.py, I import from myapp/models.py and have this:

```
    from django.contrib.auth import user_logged_in
    from django.dispatch.dispatcher import receiver
...

    @receiver(user_logged_in)
    def remove_other_sessions(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
        # remove other sessions
        Session.objects.filter(usersession__user_acc=user).delete()

        # save current session
        request.session.save()

        # create a link from the user to the current session (for later removal)
        UserSession.objects.get_or_create(
            user_acc=user,
            session_manager=Session.objects.get(pk=request.session.session_key)
        )
```

I am not using a custom user model.  When I run this code, it works properly when the user logs in the first time and creates an entry in the usersession table.  After that I have problems:

1. If I login a second user, it logs them in, but it replaces the first user's session info with the second user's in the usersession table.  I never see more than one entry in the usersession table, which is the last user to successfully login.
2. Worse, if I attempt to login the first user a second time (and this works even if there is no other user logged in).  It removes the entry in the usersession table, but fails with an Update Error:

> UpdateError at /
> No exception message supplied

3. Once the entry has been deleted from the usersession table (as in 2 above), a user that is logged in can login to a new session...

I think it is the request.session.save() call that is causing the update error, but I'm at a loss, and I don't understand why I only get one entry in the usersession table when multiple accounts are successfully logged in.  My understanding of how it should work is that the second login should successfully login, but the first login should be kicked out.

Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong, would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks--

Al

Comment: What if you wrap the entire trigger in a `try`-`except` and print the exception raised by the handler?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you meant, but I wrapped everything inside of the remove_other_sessions() function in a try except.  The Error that I print out says "<class 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.base.UpdateError'>.  The error that shows in the browser is: SuspiciousOperation at /accounts/login/
The request's session was deleted before the request completed. The user may have logged out in a concurrent request, for example.

Comment: I've tried logging in three different users together.  They all login, but the usersession table only shows one entry, which is for the last session logged in...  As none should be kicked out, I should have three entries.  Thoughts?

Comment: I finally gave up and used this similar solution with a middleware component:  [link](https://dev.to/fleepgeek/prevent-multiple-sessions-for-a-user-in-your-django-application-13oo)