# How to restrict user in Django to login through only one device, window or tab?

Tags: python, django

I am looking to develop a functionality  to enable the user to login to only one place , if he tries to  login from another device or tab then he will get logout from the previos tab or device, i didnt find any good solutios to implement, any help is appreciated

Comment: try this anaswer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50834410/15042684

Comment: @amadousow does it work for another tab also? I guess it's not.

Comment: i did not try it.